# Redirect to action is adding %20 at end of url after adding SSL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ssl, heroku, openssl

Before I added my SSL certificate it worked fine but not now.

I am using mailchimp api to subscribe an email to a newsletter. When email is successful the page should redirect to "mydomain.com/home/contact". But after adding SSL it redirects to "mydomain.com/home/contact%20" and gives me the page not found error.

Why is this and how can I fix it?

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 2):

There must be an extra space at the end. That is the reason it is being encoded to %20. Check the code where you are generating the link.

Comment: No the code is fine, when I run it on my local machine it works fine. Only occurs while the application is deployed